# Bedeutung von Klinik im Befund

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich habe einen Befund von meinem Arzt bekommen in dem steht "[...] bei sehr eindrucksvoller Klinik mit hochgradigem Verdacht auf [...]".

Was bedeutet Klink hier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je nach Kontext könnte man für "**Klinik**" in erster Näherung "klinische Symptome" bzw. "klinische Diagnose" verwenden, für "**eindrucksvolle Klinik**" demnach etwa eindrucksvolle / gravierende Symptome, die bei der Diagnose festgestellt wurden.

---

**[Roche Medizin-Lexikon](http://www.gesundheit.de/lexika/medizin-lexikon/klinik-2)**: Klinik (2) - das klin. Bild = Charakteristika (Symptome, Verlauf etc.) einer Krankheit.

---

*Unter Umständen handelt es sich bei "eindrucksvolle Klinik" um eine weniger gebräuchliche Variante von "eindeutige Klinik". Dann wäre der Ausdruck auch passend als Gegensatz zu "diskrete Klinik". "Diskret" bedeutete dann soviel wie "verborgen" oder "schwer zu klassifizierend", "eindrucksvoll" bedeutete dann "unverwechselbar", "leicht zu klassifizierend", eben "eindeutig". Da es sich hier um medizinische Fachsprache handelt, wird eine gesicherte Auskunft wohl erst von jemandem kommen, der oder die im Gesundheitswesen tätig ist.*

---

(Die primäre Wörterbuchdefinition von "Klinik" als Synonym von "Krankenhaus" bleibt hier ganz außer Acht, da offensichtlich unpassend. Außerdem noch kurz der obligatorische Hinweis, dass ich weder Mediziner bin noch einen irgendwie gearteten medizinischen Ratschlag erteilen möchte.)

---

(Since the Question is also interesting from a translator's point of view, I am leaving the initial version of my Answer in place, as shown below.)

A quick search finds **[this paper](http://www.kup.at/kup/pdf/6814.pdf)** with a bilingual German/English abstract. In the abstract, *Klinik* appears twice. Here are the relevant passages, first in German and then in English. I have bolded the portions in the English abstract that seem to correspond to *Klinik*.

Excerpt 1

> Aufgrund der unspezifischen Symptomatik und der teilweise diskreten
> Klinik ist die rein klinische Diagnose für den behandelnden Arzt oft
> sehr schwierig zu stellen.
>
> Because of various **unspecific** symptoms and **signs** clinical
> diagnosis is often very difficult.

Excerpt 2

> Neben dem wenig invasiven D-Dimertest wurden in den vergangenen Jahren
> verschiedene Score-Systeme, wie die Wells-Scores oder der
> Revised-Geneva-Score, entwickelt, die sich alle auf Anamnese und
> Klinik stützen.
>
> Besides the low-invasive test for elevated D-Dimers new score systems
> like the Wells Scores or the Revised Geneva Scores have been
> developed, which calculate the clinical probability using findings
> from **clinical examination** and history.

In the body of the paper, we find *Klinik* with the adjective *eindrucksvoll*:

> Bei den 3 Patienten mit TVT geht aus der Krankengeschichte hervor, daß
> die **eindrucksvolle Klinik** alleine reichte, um eine Bildgebung zu
> veranlassen.

Here I would propose the following draft translation:

> As to the three patients with DVT, their respective patient histories
> indicate that the **evident gravity of their symptoms** alone sufficed
> to call for a [**medical imaging**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_imaging) procedure to be performed.

(Alternative translations of *eindrucksvolle Klinik* might include phrases such as "florid symptoms" etc.)

Needless to say, the foregoing is not medical advice. Check with your physician to make certain you understand fully any diagnoses.